# How to do financial planning?

Tags: financial-literacy, business

I'm not doing this for any entity other than me. I run a business and I'm doing some financial goal-setting for the next few years. What I'm trying to achieve with this is setting numeric goals with particular dates on which I want to achieve them, so I know what I need to do get there. I know planning only goes so far, but I think it's a good idea nonetheless.

I'm trying to go further than just "revenue, profit margin, IG followers" etc. I'm working with eCommerce, if this helps. My question is:

Do you have any method/frame/set of questions that you use for your financial planning? I'm trying to look into the next 5 years

Comment: Revenue and profit are basics for a reason-- they're pretty much universal and pretty objective.  You could certainly add goals for other financial ratios depending on the specifics of your business.  Maybe you want to track inventory turn time, for example, but maybe your business is structured so it doesn't actually hold inventory.  Other metrics would really depend on the specific goals of your business-- Instagram followers doesn't strike me as all that useful for most stores but it may be very meaningful to your business.

Comment: Hey, thanks a lot, your comment actually gave me an idea of some metrics that I can track. Speed to turning inventory is a good one. And yes, IG is rather important for our business since we're very much visual and most of our marketing efforts (and sales) come from the platform. Thank you